# Changing array element value using substring

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here, I am amending an array element using `substring(0,4)` method, but throwing this error in console.

```
Javascript ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
```

Normally we use like

```
obj1.messages[2].splice(2, 1);  //To delete the particular array elements
```

But, I need to delete the particular value of the array element "**2012**1224" by taking substring. And re-assign the value to **1000**

How it is possible?

```js
var obj = {
    equipments:'first',
    messages:['20121224','20131123','20141025'],
}
console.log(obj);

obj1 = obj;
if (obj1["equipments"] == 'first' ) {
    // obj1.messages[2].splice(2, 1); 
    alert(obj1.messages[2].substring(0,4));
    delete obj1.messages[2].substring(0,4);
    obj1.messages[2].substring(0,4) = '1000';
}
console.log(obj1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: The value of obj1.messages[2].substring(0,4) should change to 1000.

Comment: @UIDesigner: Strings are immutable. You cannot change them. You can only create a new string by modifying the current string with changes required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve it using.

```
obj1.messages[2] = '1000' + obj1.messages[2].substring(4);
```

```js
var obj = {
    equipments:'first',
    messages:['20121224','20131123','20141025'],
}
console.log(obj);

obj1 = obj;
if (obj1["equipments"] == 'first' ) {
    obj1.messages[2] = '1000' + obj1.messages[2].substring(4) ;
    alert( obj1.messages[2])
}
console.log(obj1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what this means substring(4) ? No.of characters that I am changing?

Comment: @UIDesigner, It will get [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) starting from 4 to end of string. `str.substring(indexA[, indexB])` where `indexB` is optional

Comment: If I want to change substring(4,6) --> 12   How can I use this?

Comment: @UIDesigner, `obj1.messages[2] =obj1.messages[2].substring(0,4) + 'Whatever' + obj1.messages[2].substring(6);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var newString='1000'+obj1.messages[2].substring(4,obj1.messages[2].length);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because substring returns the part of that string that is specified, in your case the first 4 chars.
To replace the value you should use replace, something like:

`obj1.messages[2] = obj1.messages[2].replace(/201\d/, '1000');`

Comment: (-1) No need for regex, you haven't enforced the start of the string, and no idea why you are only catering for the 4th digit to be variable.

Comment: IMVHO replace is more suited for this context. My example is only an example that solve Rory's problem.